# What's wrong in this syntax?

Tags: mysql, wamp

I installed WAMP on my laptop running windows 8 and I am trying to set password for mysql, but every time I hit enter it gives syntax error.

Here is the code I am typing in cmd prompt:

```
mysql> set password for 'root'@'localhost'-password<'root'>;
```

Hit enter

> ERROR 1064 <42000>: You have an error in our SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '-password<'root'>' at line 1

I am running WAMPSERVER 2.2 and I have MySQL5.5.24 version.

Please help...

Comment: This may help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html): There has to be a `=` before password, not a `-`. Furthermore, you should just use normal brackets `()` for the `password()` function and not `<>`:

```
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('root');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SET password FOR 'root'@'localhost' = password('new_password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the password part that is wrong, use this:

```
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('your password');
```

`=` instead of `-` and `(` instead of `<`.

Here are [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my machine:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR `user1`@`localhost` = PASSWORD('secret');
```